# Jquery Lazy Loading not working properly in Production but working on UAT and local IIS

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, web-deployment

I am Using Jquery Lazy loading( version 1.X) and flex slider for image sliding.

Everything is working fine in local IIS and UAT environment. After deploying in production image is not visible.

I have attached screen shots ( for both production and UAT) here.

**Javascript:**

```
  $("img.lazy").lazyload({
       threshold: 200                
   });
```

**HTML:**

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="/~/media/images/mob-sliders/sliders/upvc-doors/upvc_doors_02.jpg" alt="uPVC Door Image 14" draggable="false" src="/~/media/images/mob-sliders/sliders/upvc-doors/upvc_doors_02.jpg" style="display: block;">
```

Image[image]:

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in the browser console? When you look at your Networking tab do you see any 404s for images? Do those network requests look the same as they do in your UAT environment?

Comment: Hello @arjabbar , Thanks for your reply. No, I don't have 404s for images.